# how would you function take(g,n) that takes a generator g as an argument and returns a list containing the first n values of g

Tags: python

This is my approach

```
def take(g,n):
    for i in range(10):
        yield random.randint(g)
        return n
```

Comment: The code you posted does not do what the title says, at all

Comment: Totally lost as to how to handle this, learning python but I've been stuck on this for too long.

Comment: Thought id post an approach rather than just leaving a question.

Comment: See the `take()` recipe in the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) documentation.

Comment: What does `random.randint` have to do with the problem?

Comment: SHouldn't that be `yield from g()`?

Comment: Your code is a generator as well, it doesn't return a list.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do this?

```py
def take(g, n):
    return [next(g) for _ in range(n)]
```

it takes a generator g, and a count n as an argument and returns a list containing the first n values of g

Answer (score 0):

If you are not certain that your generator will produce N values, you could use zip to get as many as you can (without exceeding N):

```
r = [ v for v,_ in zip(generator(),range(N)) ]
```

or, if you are allowed to use libraries, you could use islice from itertools:

```
r = [*islice(generator(),10)]
```